# How can I prevent a QWidget from painting, but still respond to events?

Tags: qt, opengl, paint, qwidget

I have a `QGLWidget` that renders an OpenGL scene inside a Qt application. I would like to add some other translucent Qt widgets that are overlaid on top of the `QGLWidget`. This is more difficult than with standard widgets since the OpenGL drawing context is unknown to Qt's painter classes. So, if I just do the obvious thing and place a transparent toolbar on top of the `QGLWidget` for instance, the transparent part of the toolbar instead renders black (it doesn't have access to the OpenGL frame buffer when painting).

It seems that the recommended way for handling this sort of thing is to [overpaint the 2D content after drawing the OpenGL scene](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/opengl-overpainting.html). The linked example seems very straightforward, as long as you're just drawing simple shapes. Instead, what I would like to do is to defer the painting of some child `QWidget` objects to be done inside the paint event for the `QGLWidget`.

So, my problem boils down to this:

1. Prevent the overlay `QWidget`s from painting in the normal, 2D context.
2. In the paint event handler for the `QGLWidget`, paint the overlays after painting the 3D scene that makes up the background.

The second item on this list seems to be simple: I can use `QWidget::render()` inside the `QGLWidget`'s paint event to draw the desired widgets on top of the viewport. This works just fine.

The first item is more tricky: I need a way to prevent the widgets from painting during the normal course of events and only paint them in the `QGLWidget`'s paint handler. One obvious way to do this is to hide the overlays using `QWidget::hide()`. This does allow me to paint the widgets atop the OpenGL scene as I would like. However, since the widgets are hidden, they do not respond to mouse or keyboard events. As an example, I'm using a `QToolBar` with a few buttons on it, and the toolbar is painted properly, but is non-functional (none of the buttons respond to clicks). So, if going down this path, it seems that I would need a way to force the widget to still respond to events even though it is hidden.

Another approach that I've tried is to intercept the `QToolBar`'s paint event using an event filter, with the goal of preventing the toolbar from painting itself. However, the toolbar is still rendered; I'm assuming that this is because the various buttons on the toolbar are child widgets that are still painted, even if I intercept the parent's paint event.

Any ideas on a way that I could accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't understand your issue completely, but I'll try to answer the question stated in the title. You should use event filters. Install an event filter using `widget->installEventFilter(object)`, where `widget` is a widget you want to block painting, and `object` is an object of any of your QObject-derived classes. Reimplement `eventFilter` of this class:

```
bool MyClass::eventFilter(QObject* object, QEvent* event) {
  if (event->type() == QEvent::Paint) { return true; }
  return false;
}
```

When you return true from your eventFilter, the event is filtered and paint doesn't occur.

You can also try to use `widget->setUpdatesEnabled(false)` to temporarily disable painting. Don't forget to re-enable it when you're done.

Comment: Or just do `event->ignore()` if the `paintEvent(...)` in case the widget is a custom widget.